# How to display {} in hiccup?

Tags: angularjs, clojure, hiccup

I am working on an angular app, where I need to display some angular expression in this form:

```
{{"Hello," name}}
```

In Hiccup, {} have a special meaning, and is used for attributes, how to use it for angular syntax ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the point of view of Hiccup, this will be one of the literal parts of the output, passed as a string:

```
(hiccup.core/html [:p "{{\"Hello,\" name}}"])
;= "<p>{{\"Hello,\" name}}</p>"

(hiccup.core/html [:p {:class "{{foo}}"}])
;= "<p class=\"{{foo}}\" />"
```

So, there is no clash, because the `{}` of Clojure syntax and the `{}` of Angular's default interpolation markers occur on different "levels" in the source (Angular's markers being written inside strings).

Answer (score 2):

Do not know hiccup, but in Angular with [$interpolateProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolateProvider) you can change `startSymbol` (normally `{{`) and `endSymbol` (normally `}}`) to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$interpolateProvider` in your config](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolateProvider) to change the default angular's templating symbols.